# JPA insertable = false updatable = false id not updated on creation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

We have 2 entities with a @ManyToOne relationship.

When we create an instance of EntityB within a @Transactional method, entityAId (insertable = false updatable = false), is not updated automatically - even though that the entityA instance was already persisted.

Is there a way around this? Do we have to update it manually in the ctor?

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public EntityA() {
       super();
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EntityA entityA;
    @Column(name = "entityA_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long entityAId;    

    public EntityB() {
        super();
    }

    public EntityB(EntityA entityA) {
        super();
        this.entityA = EntityA;
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Also tried the following, but still entityAId = null within the transaction (even though entityA was persisted before).

```
@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EntityA entityA;
    @Column(name = "entityA_id")
    private Long entityAId;
   ...
}
```

Comment: How are you doing to persist `EntityB` associated with `EntityA`? Edit the answer to add the code, please. The fist code snippet posted should work if you created the entityB using its constructor and passing the entityA, so I think the problem is related with the logic and transaction. Another comment, the second code you posted won't persist the relationship if you don't set the correct `entityAId` value.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate is not going to populate entity fields 'on the fly' (when you change some other fields or similar). It is also not going to do it on persist/flush (exceptions being some special fields like id and version).

Non-insertable/non-updatable fields are populated when entity instances are fetched from the DB. So, to make such fields initialized/refreshed by Hibernate in the same transaction in which you perform changes to the underlying columns they are mapped to, you should first flush the session and then either:

1. clear the session and re-read the entities;
2. or, [refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) the entities for which you want to reflect such kind of changes.

Answer (score 0):

To update the `id` field a persist action of the object is required. By default, objects in field `entityA` are not automatically persisted when persisting an object of `EntityB`.

I see two possible solutions:

A) Use `cascade`

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private EntityA entityA;
```

(or use `CascadeType.ALL`)

B) Persist `entityA` manually

```
entityManager.persist(entityA);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it also the case when entityA was already persisted to the DB before we created entityB?(in a different transaction)

Answer (score 0):

To me your mapping does not look right. `@ManyToOne` or any other association defined between entities but you have defined it on `entityAId`. Ideally it should be entity (an here you should use `insertable = false updatable = false`)and you should have separate field  `entityAId` with `@column` defined on it. Now you should update this field yourself.

If you want to handle hibernate for you  remove `insertable = false updatable = false`